# Error creating bean in dependency injection with spring-boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection

Here is my code - https://github.com/iyngaran/to-do-list

I have UserRepository class in `info.iyngaran.core.auth.repository` package and it is annotated with `@Repository`.

When I try to inject it in `CustomUserDetailsService` class which is in `info.iyngaran.core.auth.security` package, I am getting the following error.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'customUserDetailsService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'info.iyngaran.core.auth.repository.UserRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

Can somebody help me to find out the issue on this ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the issue by adding the following line to the spring boot main class.

```
@EnableJpaRepositories({"info.iyngaran.core","info.iyngaran.todolistapi"})
```

and that resolved my issue. Here is the details - https://stackoverflow.com/a/53172477/9348637

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is component scanning. So arrange your code following way

Move your `TodolistApiApplication` class at the package root `info.iyngaran`

and clear the clutter

```
package info.iyngaran;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import java.util.TimeZone;

@SpringBootApplication
public class TodolistApiApplication {

    @PostConstruct
    void init() {
        TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TodolistApiApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

also use constructor injection (not mandatory for the fix). field injection is very bad practice

```
private final UserRepository userRepository;

public CustomUserDetailsService(UserRepository userRepository) {
    this.userRepository = userRepository;
}
```

Comment: I don't see any issues with component scanning. I have some other components in the package, example - LoggerConfig, which is working without any issues.

Comment: Did u try what i suggested

Comment: No, I want to keep the classes in a separate package.

Comment: You only have to move one class `TodolistApiApplication` to package root