# Parameter 0 of constructor in required a bean of type that could not be found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have problem running my spring boot application on production environment. Everything still works fine under the local environment.

This is my error

```
Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.tkg.product.service.impl.LocationService required a bean of type 'com.tkg.product.repository.CountryRepositoryInterface' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.tkg.product.repository.CountryRepositoryInterface' in your configuration.
```

This is my code:

**LocationService**

```
package com.tkg.product.service.impl;

import com.tkg.product.entity.Country;
import com.tkg.product.entity.Destination;
import com.tkg.product.repository.CountryRepositoryInterface;
import com.tkg.product.repository.DestinationRepositoryInterface;
import com.tkg.product.service.LocationServiceInterface;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Sort;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class LocationService implements LocationServiceInterface {

    private final CountryRepositoryInterface countryRepository;
    
    private final DestinationRepositoryInterface destinationRepository;

    @Override
    public List<Country> countries() {
        return countryRepository.findAll(Sort.by(Sort.Direction.ASC, "name"));
    }

    @Override
    public List<Destination> findDestinationByCountry(List<Long> countryIds) {
        return destinationRepository.findByCountryIdIn(countryIds);
    }
}
```

**CountryRepositoryInterface**

```
package com.tkg.product.repository;

import com.tkg.product.entity.Country;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public interface CountryRepositoryInterface extends JpaRepository<Country, Long> {
}
```

I tried replacing @Component with @Repository but everything is still the same.

Thanks everyone

Comment: Can you share also `entity` Country class ? and also what version of spring-boot are you using ?

Comment: Please specify the version of Spring Boot you are using, and add your entity (including the imports). The `@Component` is useless on a Spring Data repository interface. Finally make sure your `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class is in the `com.tkg.product` package and not some sub-package.

Answer (score 0):

add @EnableJpaRepositories to your main class with basepackages

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Check out -->
[Spring @ComponentScan doesn't work on @Repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53172317/spring-componentscan-doesnt-work-on-repository)

From above link:
In order to let spring knows what DataSource is related to what Repository you should define it at the @EnableJpaRepositories annotation.